# Deploying Resources on OCI using terraform/Linux

Tags: linux, oracle, terraform, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

*I essentially want to work to being able to create a Kubernetes cluster in my compartment within OCI. I am a beginner to cloud technology in general so many of my questions en route to this goal will probable basic*

**Where I am currently:**
I have created a virtual machine Within the OCI console which is running Linux 8. Within this linux machine i have downloaded OCI CLI. (i am not even sure if this was the correct thing to do) i have used the private and public keys in doing this.

**What i currently need to know from the readers:**

1. How do i ensure that my cli is connected to the oci console. I know there is a 'ping' function in powershell. Is there something similar in linux to just show me that i know have access to the oci console from my linux/oci cli, now that i've configure public/private keys?
2. After connection is established i'm assuming the next step would be to download terraform into a route compartment in my linux machine right? After that i create the tf scripts (saved in a directory) and run terraform from the linux cli right?

Any pointers would be appreciated. Pointers such as where would the terraform scripts be saved; within the storage available on the cloud, or on my local machine?

Comment: Do not ask multiple questions per post. Ask one question, show your work, the exact error message or result and expectations. Start by reading this post: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

Essentially you are referring to multiple things here. I suggest you to approach one thing at a time. For example, "[Setting up OCI CLI](https://docs.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/Content/API/SDKDocs/cliinstall.htm)", "[Using Terraform on OCI](https://docs.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/Content/API/SDKDocs/terraformgetstarted.htm)", "U[nderstand OKE Service](https://docs.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/Content/ContEng/Concepts/contengoverview.htm)" and then "How to deploy OKE using Terraform". This will give you enough pointers about what and where to start first.

In order to test OCI CLI's functionality, just execute some "list" commands and see you do NOT get "Authorization failure" or other messages. You should ideally get a list of what you have asked for, for example, a list of Users or Compute Instances using commands like "oci compute instance list --compartment-id ".

As for OKE Terraform Modules, [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8016720/john-hanley) should be very useful.

Finally you can either execute Terraform Modules from a VM or by using OCI [Resource Manager](https://docs.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/Content/ResourceManager/Concepts/resourcemanager.htm) service.